# On Ubuntu 22.04 Samba 4.15.13 with option "hide unreadable" hides all directories not having "read attributes" set in ACL

Tags: 22.04, samba, acl

In smb.conf we set the attribute "hide unreadable = yes". After this a user can only see folders on which the ACL "read attributes" is set, although he is allowed to read and write to the folder.

If I set the Attribute "read attributes" on the folder, the user can see the folder.

It seems to be u [a?] bug that could be fixed in Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm not sure. Does anyone any idea how to fix this problem?